# python-ldap on Windows 64bit fails

Tags: python, ldap

I am trying to use the python-ldap library with Python 2.7 on Windows 7 64 bit. I have 64bit Python and I was able to get most libraries up and running with the help of the excellent repository run by Mr. Gohlke: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

However, on python-ldap I stumped: when I install it and then try to include it:

```
import ldap
```

I get the following error:

```
File "[...]\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ldap._ldap import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

The `%1` file is `_ldap.pyd`

Am I doing anything wrong?

---

This question is now moot. I have had the problem as described when I installed `python-ldap-2.4.13.win-amd64-py2.7`. I then uninstalled and tried installing win32 version from PyPI, that of course did not work either. Then I uninstalled that version, and re-installed (from the same exe file) the 64bit version. Now everything works.

EDIT SUMMARY:

- changed Python version to 2.7 (error in the original post)
- described how the problem went away

Comment: I am sorry, the error message I pasted into my question was from the 32bit version I installed in the hope it would help. But I have had very similar error message from the 64bit version `python-ldap-2.4.13.win-amd64-py2.7.exe`. However, this morning I have uninstalled the 32 bit version, re-installed the 64 bit version and everything works. I have no clue what happened. Many thanks for your help, anyway, and for the great work on 64bit Python libraries.

Comment: I'm getting this error with Python 3.4 64-bit, and I can't seem to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

you can install the version of Osuch here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap/

select the version appropriate

source: http://www.osuch.org/python-ldap